# Trying to use a Predicate to extract certain data into a list C#

Tags: c#, list

I have an instance that contains a List that contains a set of records. I have created another instance of this list where I only want to pull out the active records, but this is the error it throws:

> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Namespace.Class]' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Class]'.

Here is my code

```
public async Task CompareList(List<ListClass> listInstance1)
{
    List<ListClass> listInstance2 = new List<ListClass>();
    listInstance2 = (List<ListClass>)listInstance1.Where(x => x.Active == "A");
}
```

Comment: Add `.ToList()` to the end of the second statement? Are you aware of what `IEnumerable`s are? In addition, why is your method `async`, there's nothing being awaited and there's no other reason to return a `Task`. Why do you initialize `listInstance2`, just to overwrite that on the next line?

Comment: @gunr2171 that did it! Thank you I'm still pretty new to C#  and will give you credit if youll post the answer. I need to familiarize myself better with IEnumerables, the reason it is async is because my real code calls with an await later in the function i  was just simplifying what i had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in your code is that you try to cast `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`

you have two options, either use `.ToList()` as suggested in the other answer, or pass the filtered list as a parameter to construct a new list as shown in the following code:

```
public async Task CompareList(List<ListClass> listInstance1)
{
 List<ListClass> listInstance2 = new(listInstance1.Where(x => x.Active == "A"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in declaring a new variable which u override with a new list on the next line. Best to do this in one line.

```cs
public async Task CompareList(List<ListClass> listInstance1)
{
    List<ListClass> listInstance2 = listInstance1
        .Where(x => x.Active == "A")
        .ToList();
}
```